# U.K. calls U.S. using C# and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty familiar with web programming in C# but I have a challenge I'm unsure how to address?

I need to monitor two different domains to make sure they are up. I need abc.us/Test.aspx to call abc.uk/Test.aspx and pass in a distinct value (request.querystring?) and I want to inspect that parameter and if it's not null I want to call the US site back with same parameter (an int++;) and just keep doing this.

I really just need to monitor both sites and make sure they are up. Is there a good way to do this? Best practice? Web service?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty subjective, but I think a better approach would be to monitor them from a Windows service. Just try and hit each one on a regular interval and if you don't get a response--well I guess you know which one's down.

Comment: Yep just fire off webrequests from a service and check the return statusCode. If its 400+ then there was an error

Comment: So just webclient.downloadstring("site.asp"); Parse the string for errors and if none then good to go.

Comment: Have you had a look at pingdom, pingability and similar services? They are relatively cheap for monitoring sites for you.

Comment: Depending on which version of .NET you're using, you should use HttpClient instead of WebRequest. It has many nice features and is worthy of becoming the default tool in your toolbelt. If you need to parse the returned HTML, then you can use the HTML Agility Pack. If you need to have script on the page run, then you can use a WebBrowser control.